# How to display data in MaterialTable while using with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am using `MaterialTable` which showing static data perfectly but when I am trying to make data dynamic which is coming from `redux` store then error is coming. So I want to display user data in table which is [image]

While the code is

```
      import React from 'react';
  import { Fragment, useEffect, useState, useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
  import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

  export default function MaterialTableUser() {
    let user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);
  console.log(user)
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
      columns: [
        { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Email', field: 'email' }

      ],
      data: [
        { name: 'Mehmet', email: 'Baran' },

      ],
    });

    return (
      <MaterialTable
        title="Editable Example"
        columns={state.columns}
        data={state.data}
        editable={{
          onRowAdd: newData =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
                setState(prevState => {
                  const data = [...prevState.data];
                  data.push(newData);
                  return { ...prevState, data };
                });
              }, 600);
            }),
          onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
                if (oldData) {
                  setState(prevState => {
                    const data = [...prevState.data];
                    data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                    return { ...prevState, data };
                  });
                }
              }, 600);
            }),
          onRowDelete: oldData =>
            new Promise(resolve => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
                setState(prevState => {
                  const data = [...prevState.data];
                  data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                  return { ...prevState, data };
                });
              }, 600);
            }),
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

For making it dynamic I did like this `data : user` in above code but that could not work I also did this

```
data: [
    { name:(user && user[0].name), email: (user && user[0].email)},

  ]
```

and also `data:user` but nothing is working.

One other thing is `redux dev tool` also not working with `MaterialTable` code why ?

Comment: In code snippet you are using useSelector to get user data, where are you fetching for table data also did you added the redux tool code to the store to enable redux dev, Kindly add the store snippet too

Comment: Redux tool is working without MaterialTable , but after including MaterialTable  its stops working .

Comment: did you checked this https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/930

Comment: For making it dynamic I did like this `data : user` in above code but that could not work I also did this 
data: [
        { name:(user && user[0].name), email: (user && user[0].email)},

      ]

Comment: just try log that one like  let user = useSelector(state => console.log(state)); and check whether user data is coming, are you using multiple reducers and combining it

Comment: Yes off course user data is coming, I have shared image for this.

Comment: then you can use it isn't whats the issue on it, and do a ternary check on the render part if its an async call